# Different sequance problem

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Let $x \in \Bbb{R}^+$, $a_1=x, a_2=x^{x}$ and $a_n=x^{a_{n-1}} \ \forall n\geq 3 $
$$S=\{x \in \Bbb{R}^+: a_n \rightarrow a \in \Bbb{R} \}$$ find the $sup(S)$ I can show $ 0<x<1  \vee 1<x<\sqrt{2}\Rightarrow x\in S $ but I couldn't do the sup part please help me

Comment: It is a tetration issue : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration